# DRF doesnt populate field label when using source

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So, I have some model with few fields I want to expose over REST API:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField(verbose_name="Field 1")
    field2 = models.TextField(verbose_name="Field 2")
```

and have corresponding serializer:

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field2')
```

This way it works fine: using GET I retrieve fields values, and using OPTIONS I retrieve secondary fields information (e.g. if the field is required, help text, and **label**)

The problem is that I don't want to expose real fields name, and I want to use some other name instead, for example:
`field1` and `secondField`.

For that I modify my serializer:

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    secondField = serializers.CharField(source='field2')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1', 'secondField')
```

Now I receive correct values on GET, but fields labels are wrong on OPTIONS: for second field I receive "Secondfield" instead of "Field 2"

How do I get correct field label when using `source`?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be solved by using `serializers.Serializer` instead of `serializers.ModelSerializer` and explicitly defining the serializer fields.

You may need to define a `.create()` and `update()` method by implementing the `.create()` and `.update()` methods in your `MySerializer` class in order to ensure you are able to return complete object instances based on the validated data.